# Delete Outlook.MailItem from the Deleted Items folder don't work

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

After moving an Outlook.MailItem from inbox to "Deleted Items" folder, I am trying to delete permanently the MailItem by doing below:

```
Outlook.MailItem olmi = omi.Move(ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems));
olmi.Delete();
```

Outlook MailItem is moved correctly from inbox to deleted items folder but it is not being deleted from the Deleted items folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a new `MailItem` instance and then call the `Delete` method. The [GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) can help with retrieving a new instance.

Comment: Could you please post a piece of code? I am very newbie with Outlook Add-ins sorry.